# Media Style Notification Issue

Tags: java, android

I am facing issue in MediaStyle() in Android. You can see the issue in **".setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()"**
This is my imports,

```
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.AudioAttributes;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.PlaybackStateCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import java.io.IOException;
```

//Notification

```
private void showMediaStyleNotification(String imageUrl, String title) {
    // Build the notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)  // Set content title using the title from the intent
            .setContentText("Notification Text")
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground))
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    .setMediaSession(new MediaSessionCompat(this, "tag").getSessionToken())
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1)
                    .setShowCancelButton(true)
                    .setCancelButtonIntent(
                            MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                                    this,
                                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP
                            )
                    )
            )
            .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(
                    R.drawable.play_icon,
                    "Play",
                    MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                            this,
                            PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY
                    )
            ))
            .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(
                    R.drawable.pause_icon,
                    "Pause",
                    MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                            this,
                            PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE
                    )
            ));

    // Load the image from the URL and set it as a large icon
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).get();
        builder.setLargeIcon(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Show the notification
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    }
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

I tried **"import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle;"** but not working.
Also used this dependency latest version **"implementation "androidx.media:media:1.7.0""**

Answer (score 0):

Try creating `androidx.media.app` one:

```
new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
```

Comment: When I add this i got error in Builder

Comment: Please add error messages in your post. @SriramS